# Finding my Valid RSA Host Key

Tags: key, rsa, host

I recently migrated one of my domains to a new hosting service, so I switched the DNS name servers, moved the content to the new hosting service, etc.

Now I am trying to log into the site (now on the new host) and there seems to be a problem on my own machine regarding this issue.

Question: Where and How do I find the new correct RSA key that the below error message is saying that I need?

Error Message (Details disguised):

> evan-stites-claytons-macbook-2171:~ estites$ ssh root@EXAMPLE.com
>   POSSIBLE DNS SPOOFING DETECTED!
>   The RSA host key for EXAMPLE.com has changed,
>   and the key for the corresponding IP address XXX.XXX.xxx.xx
>   is unchanged. This could either mean that
>   DNS SPOOFING is happening or the IP address for the host
>   and its host key have changed at the same time.
>   Offending key for IP in /Users/estites/.ssh/known_hosts:2
>   WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!
>   IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
>   Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
>   It is also possible that the RSA host key has just been changed.
>   The fingerprint for the RSA key sent by the remote host is
>   xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:b5:21:f1:1f:39:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx.
>   Please contact your system administrator.
>   Add correct host key in /Users/estites/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
>   Offending key in /Users/estites/.ssh/known_hosts:1
>   RSA host key for example.com has changed and you have requested strict checking.
>   Host key verification failed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can just delete the line with the old host key in `/Users/estites/.ssh/known_hosts`. You'll be prompted to accept the now-unknown host key the first time you try SSHing again.

Answer (score 0):

If you know it's a false alarm, just remove the offending keys from your `known_hosts` file; according to the error message they're on lines 1 and 2